# Alternatives to Photoshop and Illustrator

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative, photoshop

I just try to move completely from Windows to Ubuntu. I am a web designer and developer, the development part is awesome in Ubuntu but I am missing the design part.

What I used to work with is Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator.
Are there any good alternatives for Ubuntu available?

Comment: Alex have you tried Gimp or inkscape? you can find these and more in the Ubuntu software center Gimp is more of a Photoshop alternative and inkscape is the Illustrator alternative

Answer (score 12):

In Open Source realm, you can find many alternatives to what you want. I just want to point for something, don't ever treat applications as if they are the same, You can't find SAME alternative for Photoshop, instead you can find mostly all properties and maybe sometimes more but you have to learn how to use.

Photoshop alternatives:

- [gimp](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwj09LCjgdrGAhWi8nIKHeD4B80&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gimp.org%2F&ei=Sa6kVbSsK6LlywPg8Z_oDA&usg=AFQjCNHSDGuHdZTSGB1PiMFTSSn1zSDRCw&sig2=O5s7foZACAu2t2w5XZDpVg)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gimp
  ```

[image]

- [krita](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjC5p7ZgdrGAhUC7nIKHRAOBwc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkrita.org%2F&ei=uq6kVcKhKILcywOQnJw4&usg=AFQjCNF1_0dYbbgdWxByyzfu8y2zUw4omg&sig2=o8GjDfOdFj3NdnsQT_NQWA)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get install krita
  ```

[image]

For more options take a look: http://www.ubuntufree.com/top-5-photoshop-alternatives-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-14-10/

Illustrator Alternatives:

The best to use would be [inkscape](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiagMCDgtrGAhVKw3IKHYsCAGQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Finkscape.org%2F&ei=E6-kVdqqEcqGywOLhYCgBg&usg=AFQjCNFMvobmZ6ikZ23ctBNV4CuYoreZ-Q&sig2=SPPKWAGN65lGhexGnWmpHg&bvm=bv.97653015,d.bGQ):

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, If you like my answer then make upvote and mark as accepted instead